# Managing definitions in a COM type library with a lot of IDL interfaces

Tags: com, atl, idl, midl, typelib

I'm creating a COM type library with over one hundred interfaces. Defining all of the interfaces and coclasses in a single `library` is unreasonable... the IDL file becomes thousands of lines long! So I'm trying the idea of putting each interface in its own file, and using `import`s to satisfy its dependencies.

What strategies can I use to manage this many interfaces? I'm trying to use `import` directives everywhere, but I'm stuck trying to get them included in the TLB. I've tried `#include` in the `library`, but things seem to get funky with dependencies.

#### ExampleA.idl

```
import "oaidl.idl", "ocidl.idl";
[ uuid(...) ] interface IExampleA : IDispatch { ... }
```

#### ExampleB.idl

```
import "oaidl.idl", "ocidl.idl", "IExampleA.idl";
[ uuid(...) ] interface IExampleB : IExampleA { ... }
```

#### ExampleLibrary.idl

```
// Should I put some imports here? They won't be included in the library.
import "IExampleA.idl";
import "IExampleB.idl";

[ uuid(...) ]
library InfrastructureLib
{
    // This? Imports in a library don't actually include the types
    import "IExampleA.idl";
    import "IExampleB.idl";

    // Or this? I get class redefinition errors trying #include 
    #include "IExampleA.idl"
    #include "IExampleB.idl"

    // Is there another way?
};
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what kind of library are you writing that requires 100+ interfaces?  I think my brain would explode if I tried to use it.  If it were me I would try to group them in some logical order and separate them out into different libraries.

Comment: ^_^ We have a lot of infrastructure (logging, file I/O, etc.) and then communication classes (a bunch of classes representing different messages). I suppose I could put them into separate libraries... would importlib let me group them all into one master library then? Hmm....

Comment: Descriptions such as "I get compilation errors trying #include" are not very helpful, you know, unless you really don't care of the outcome.

Comment: They're class redefinition errors--I updated the comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think your plan to split up the interfaces into multiple tlb files is fine, however I dont understand why you appear to be generating the files by hand?

My suggestion would be to split the interfaces into multiple typelibraries but use a typelibrary editor to create them.

A type library editor comes with every version of Delphi, but if you dont have this there should be a few available on the net.

Comment: I had no idea such a thing existed... is one included with Visual Studio? I am creating COM objects and interfaces using ATL.